# Project Slider Images - Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have problem with script in WordPress name: Project Slides.

This script worked and one day just stopped. I check in console what is wrong and got this:

```
VM138 plupload-image.js?ver=4.2.2:67 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement].max_file_uploads
at Function.fa.error (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:12733)
at fa.tokenize (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:18786)
at fa.select (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:21594)
at Function.fa (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:7320)
at Function.a.find (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):9:3686)
at n.fn.init.find (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:24109)
at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):9:8931)
at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:24676)
at new a.fn.init (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):9:3137)
at n (http://www.wieczoreklab.pl/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.1 (old):2:406)
```

Then I check source code where this bug showed and this is it:

```
rwmb_image_uploaders[prefix].bind( 'FilesAdded', function( up, files )
    {
        var max_file_uploads = $( '#' + this.settings.container + ' .max_file_uploads' ).val(),
            uploaded = $( '#' + this.settings.container + ' .rwmb-uploaded' ).children().length,
            msg = 'You may only upload ' + max_file_uploads + ' file';

        if ( max_file_uploads > 1 )
            msg += 's';
```

Anyone can tell me what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace all

```
 this.settings.container
```

with (for me it's on line 67, 68, 87, 112 and 113)

```
this.settings.container.id
```

to resolve the problem.

It's worked for me on an old WordPress theme called "Inovado"